# Using JUCE Modules in an existing Objective-C iOS project in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, juce

I'm trying to somehow add and use the JUCE modules in my existing iOS project in Xcode 6. I've added the files, but I don't know how to include the headers such as JuceHeader.h, etc. to my project. I searched a lot to find a step-by-step instruction for this task but I was not successful. I'll appreciate if somebody helps me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can build the JUCE code as static library and use this library to link to your app.
Include necessary file in your project and link your project against JUCE library.

Comment: Does anyone have an example project structured this way?

Comment: you need to create new jucer file and add all the modules required by you.